# Optimizing launch time for Android app

Tags: android, launch-time

My App contains a single activity and a fragment with listView.

The `listview` items (not more than 5) are being loaded from `SQLite`. Each item comprises of 3 `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

But still it is taking more than one second to load the app.

Can someone please suggest some tips to decrease launching time of Android App.

**Code Flow:**

*onCreate method of Activity:*

```
super.onCreate()
// finding two views by ID
// initialising fragment Manager
// initialising toolbar
// setting toolbar as supportactionbar
// fileHandle initialization
// databasehandle initialization 

if (condition using filehandle) {
    // add fragmentA
} else {
   if (condition using databasehandle) {
      // add fragmentB
   } else {
      // add fragmentC
   }
   // update the filehandle
}
```

Comment: Use Traceview, `StrictMode`, etc. to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: Do you db requests in a background thread.

Comment: used traceview, got it, db operations are taking time.

Comment: Your listview is only 5, but you could try using RecyclerView. It  is much more powerful, flexible, and it has a major enhancement over ListView.